# identifier and variables in C

Tags: c

can we say that identifier are alias of variables?
are identifier and variables same?

Comment: @quixoto: I am reading from book... there is mentioned that identifier is a sequence of characters(token) that denote an object,function, or various element of C.. so can we say that identifier are variable too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To say it another way, identifiers are the names given to things (such as variables and functions). They **identify** the thing which they are naming.

Comment: if i say **#define NBYTE            15** 
now can we say that NBYTE is identifier..is it?

Answer (score 3):

No.

```
int f() { }
```

`f` is an identifier.  It is not a variable.

Comment: McNellis, that mean functions names are actually identifier..is it?

Comment: i am reading from book... there is mentioned that identifier is a sequence of characters(token) that denote an object,function, or various element of C.. so can we say that identifier are variable too.

Comment: What book are you reading from that says this?  Yes, a variable is a named object and the name is an identifier, but not all identifiers are names of objects (or variables).

Comment: i am reading book :"A complete guide to mastering the C language". writer: AUGIE HANSEN..

Answer (score 3):

No, from C99 (6.2.1):

> An identifier can denote an object; a
>   function; a tag or a member of a
>   structure,  union, or enumeration; a
>   typedef name; a label name; a macro
>   name; or a macro  parameter.

Comment: isn't variable is object ? I know it's not in technical terms but most of times we overlaps definition of variable and object.

Answer (score 3):

Identifier is the fancy term used to mean ‘name’. In C, identifiers are used to refer to a number of things: we've already seen them used to name variables and functions. They are also used to give names to some things we haven't seen yet, amongst which are labels and the ‘tags’ of structures, unions, and enums.

An identifier is used for any variable, function, data definition, etc. In the C programming language, an identifier is a combination of alphanumeric characters, the first being a letter of the alphabet or an underline, and the remaining being any letter of the alphabet, any numeric digit, or the underline. and you know about variables.
please check [C Tutorial - Chapter 1](http://www.coronadoenterprises.com/tutorials/c/chap01.htm)